# Fetch all comments/reaction for a activity in getstream

Tags: ios, swift, getstream-io

I m using below code to fetch all the reaction of an activity from getStream. But it is returning only 10 activity.
Below is the code. Pagination .none not working

```
Client.shared.reactions(forActivityId: state.activity.id, extraDataTypeOf: ReactionExtraData.self, userTypeOf: User.self) { [weak self](result) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.state.connectionStatus = .ready
            if let value = try? result.get() {
                TempLogger.log("\(value.reactions.count)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you try using Pagination with different limit? please attach code if that did not work

Comment: Pagination .none won't make an unlimited list of reactions. The limitation would be used with a default value. Use pagination parameter for paging.

Comment: I dont need pagination. I want to retrieve all reaction in a single call.

Comment: @Aashish did you ever figure this out?